# Send mail successfully through Python program but User can't receive email

Tags: python, email

I have python program to send mail to users. While some users are not able to get the mail and we didn't get any error message either. Even I send a mail to unknown(invalid) email address, the program doesn't show any error.

the following is my program .

```
  class SendEmail:
    def __init__(self, smtpserver, smtpuser, smtppass, smtpport):
        self.smtpserver = smtpserver
        self.smtpuser = smtpuser
        self.smtppass = smtppass
        self.smtpport = smtpport
    def send(self, to_list, subject, html):
        msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('ralated')
        msgRoot['Subject'] = subject
        msgRoot['From'] = self.smtpuser
        print ";".join(to_list)
        msgRoot['To'] = ";".join(to_list)
        msgRoot.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'
        msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msgRoot.attach(msgAlternative)

        msgText = MIMEText(html, 'html', 'utf-8')
        msgAlternative.attach(msgText)

        try:
            smtp = smtplib.SMTP(self.smtpserver,self.smtpport)
            #smtp.connect(self.smtpserver)

            #if self.smtppass != None:
            #     smtp.login(self.smtpuser, self.smtppass)

            smtp.sendmail(self.smtpuser, to_list, msgRoot.as_string())
        except smtplib.SMTPException,e:
            print smtplib.SMTPException,":",e
        smtp.quit()

 sendm = SendEmail("###","####",None,25)
 sendm.send(['chen_adang92@126.com'],'ECOMM Error Testing','\
           This is test     email , Please let me know If you get the mail,many thanks!')
```

Comment: Check your mail logs!

Comment: sorry, where to check mail logs?  seems there is not any logs return after run smtp.sendmail(....)

Comment: On the mail server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addressed my issue now.
it is nothing with smtp of python. 
my to-email address is extracted from a json file . The address is unicode character when i get from json.load. Some e-mail server can't accept unicode email address. so they didn't receive mail .